Is the given code for gradient descent updating the parameters sequentially or simultaneously?
I'm new to machine learning and I have been learning gradient descent algorithm. I believe this code uses simultaneous update, even though it looks like sequential update. Since the values of partial derivative are calculated before updating either w or b, that is, from the original w and b, the algorithm thus applied on individual w,b is being applied from original values. Am I wrong?

dj_dw=((w*x[i]+b-y[i])*x[i])/m
dj_db=(w*x[i]+b-y[i])/m
w=w-a*dj_dw
b=b-a*dj_db

The language is python3.
x and y are training set.
w and b are parameters that the algorithm is being applied on.
I'm using gradient descent algorithm for linear regression.
dj_dw is the partial differentiation of squared mean error cost function with respect to w. Same goes for dj_db.
Apologies for any errors, I'm new.
I tried cross checking using gemini and chatgpt and they said it was sequential, hence the confusion

I don't think this is answerable with so little code, you did not even mention what programming language is this.

Still it is too vague, I tend to say it is parallel but all depends on what the variables mean and how they were computed.

It's simultaneous because both w and b are updated before the next iteration, meaning w and b both have updated values when the next differentiation occurs.
